# C# - как правильно убить запущенный процесс и затем удалить файл?

Tags: c#

Имеется задача удалить файл с определенной папки, предварительно убив процесс запущенный с удаляемого файла. Приведённый ниже код не вызывает ошибок при написании и при сборке в Visual Studio но при открытии собранного файла процесс убивается и вылетает окошко с ошибкой и файл не удаляется, хотя должен удаляться следом за убиванием процесса. Вот это окошко:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После закрытия окошка с ошибкой я заново запускаю файл и уже файл удаляется. Т.е. ошибка вылетает именно после убивания процесса. Не могу понять где ошибка, надеюсь на Ваш профессионализм ;)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace newkill
{
    class Program
    {

        ////////
        ///////
        //////
        public static void KillProcess(string path)
        {
            Process.GetProcesses() // получаем все процессы
                .Where(p => CheckIfProcessFileEquals(p, path)) // берем только те, в которых пути к файлу совпадают
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(p => p.Kill()); // убиваем каждый
        }

        private static bool CheckIfProcessFileEquals(Process process, string path)
        {
            try
            {
                return process.MainModule.FileName.Equals(path, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase); // сравниваем пути, инорим кейс
            }
            catch (Win32Exception)
            {
                return false; // если MainModule недоступен - скипаем
            }
        }
        //////
        ///////
        ////////


        static void Main()
        {




            var path_calc = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Roaming\calc.exe";

            KillProcess(path_calc);



            // Удаляем все файл
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path_calc))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(path_calc);
            }

            Environment.Exit(0);



        }






    }
}
```

Comment: На выбор https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305428/self-deletable-application-in-c-sharp-in-one-executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то Вы просто не дожидаетесь завершения убиваемого процесса. Попробуйте так

```
.ForEach(p => {
  p.Kill();
  p.WaitForExit();
});
```